# PURI:URI how to get the actual string represented

Tags: common-lisp, drakma

[Drakma](http://weitz.de/drakma/) returns an `PURI:URI` object as a fourth return value. But I want to extract the actual string and not mess around with the object.

What is the name of the accessor as `puri:uri-string` which accesses directly the corresponding slot is not public in the package and the [documentation](http://puri.b9.com/documentation.html) is [not existing](http://opensource.franz.com/uri/uri-dist/uri.htm).

Anybody who has some experience using that package?

Currently I am using `(FORMAT nil "~a" URI)` as a quickfix, but this cannot be what the author intended.

Comment: http://www.crategus.com/books/puri/pages/puri.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `puri:render-uri`. Note that it takes a stream to render the uri to as a second argument.